# How to change a uk-button-text underline color

Tags: html, css, uikit

I need to change a UIkit button-text color and my code looks like this right now:

```css
.container-resultados-busca .escolha-resultado-pesquisa:hover {
color: rgba(154, 217, 163, 1);
}
```

```html
<button class="uk-button uk-button-text escolha-resultado-pesquisa">RESULTADOS DA PESQUISA</button>
```

The text button changes the color but the underscore doesn't. If anyone know how to fix this it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
.escolha-resultado-pesquisa:hover {
    background-color: rgba(154, 217, 163, 1);
}
```

I do not see a reference for the first container, so this should work.

Comment: This didn't work here. The first container is the container where I placed other button. Is a div inside of another div.

Comment: If you have a direct reference to a class, it should work. Are you sure that class is directly linked to the button?

Comment: Yes. It changes the text color to green but it never changes de underline color. Maybe is conflicting with the uikit class, but I'm not sure.